# window.print for mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I am working on a client app, I have a div onclick of which I load a new page and call

```
window.print()
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't work in the mobile devices, any alternative solution to this?

Comment: It is depending on the browser. You are using in your mobile device

Comment: Please refer to this list for the window. print supported device. https://wiki.appstudio.dev/Window.print()

Comment: Can refer to this too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

window.print is supported on android with chrome and edge but not firefox .
**The command is supported on iOS, Chrome on Windows and Safari and Chrome on Mac. It is not supported on Android.**

Comment: Alternate solutions?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget ,I think this help you..

Comment: GCP is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

It works on Android devices. If you can't see proper preview in mobile, set **CSS media query** for print:

```css
@media print (max-width: 767px) {
   /* write css here for mobile responsive for print */
}
```